# Android GCM messages activity - reloaded when ever the activity starts

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, listactivity

I am writing an app which has GCM in it. I am not trying to compete with Whatsapp. It should just a sort of bulletin board between all those who use this app.

The app is opened with a menu of buttons and one of them directs the user to the Messages activity.

As long as you stay on this activity, the messages are there and everything works as it should be.

But, if I go back to the menu activity and then go back into the messages activity, then all messages are gone and are not shown.

I am using ListActivity for the messages and the onCreate function, destroys the current list each time it is read.

My question is, how can I return to the messages activity without loosing them? I want to have it as in Whatsapp, when you go into Whatsapp the messages are always there!

I thought of saving the messages list into a file and then read it (or let's say the last 40-50 messages) anytime the onCreate is called. Is this a good solution? Is there any solution without saving the list to a file?

Here is some of my code inside the messages activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msg_main);

    Intent in = getIntent();

    username = in.getStringExtra("username");
    password = in.getStringExtra("password");        
    nickname = in.getStringExtra("nickname");        

    messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    txtNewMsg = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.text);
    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
}       

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        Spanned newMessageDate = Html.fromHtml("<small><i><font color=\"red\">" + currentDateandTime + "</font></i></small>" + " " + "<small><i><font color=\"blue\">" + nickname + "</font></i></small>" + "<br />" + newMessage);

        addNewMessage(new Message(newMessageDate, true));

        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

void addNewMessage(Message m)
{
    messages.add(m);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().setSelection(messages.size()-1);
}
```

The code includes: onCreate, BroadcastReceiver (GCM receiver), onDestroy and addNewMessage which adds the new message to the messages list.

Thanks for any help!

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create database with message table and users table which will store the message and users details.

Now whenever new message is come store in database and then when you open the app load limited message from table. If the app is open and message is come first store in your database and add to your list object and invalidate your listview.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Let me try this and get back to you. But think of Whatsapp, each time you open the messages, they are already there. Only if load "earlier messages" then you pull them from a remote database. Do they keep the current history in a database on the phone? Should I do the same? Anyway, I am going to do what you suggest and I'll get back to you!

Comment: Yes whatsapp store messages in device database too, even they store the image thumb in database too, when the internet connection is not available than also you can read the existing message

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! Thanks for the help. I implemented a database for the messages. Now each time you go into the activity, the old messages are loaded from the SQL database! Thanks man!